# R Time Series plot.ts()

Tags: r, plot, timeserieschart

I am trying to read in a time series and do a plot.ts(), however I am getting weird results.  Perhaps I did something wrong. I tried including the start and end dates but the output is still wrong.
Any help appreciated. Thank you.

This is the code and output:

```
sales1 <- read.csv("TimeS.csv",header=TRUE)
sales1

salesT <- ts(sales1)
salesT
plot.ts(salesT)

output:
> sales1 <- read.csv("TimeS.csv",header=TRUE)
> sales1

  year  q1  q2  q3  q4
1 1991 4.8 4.1 6.0 6.5
2 1992 5.8 5.2 6.8 7.4
3 1993 6.0 5.6 7.5 7.8
4 1994 6.3 5.9 8.0 8.4

> salesT <- ts(sales1)
> salesT

Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 4 
Frequency = 1 
  year  q1  q2  q3  q4
1 1991 4.8 4.1 6.0 6.5
2 1992 5.8 5.2 6.8 7.4
3 1993 6.0 5.6 7.5 7.8
4 1994 6.3 5.9 8.0 8.4

> plot.ts(salesT)

 It looks like I can't paste the plot.  instead of 1 graph it has 5 separate    
 plots stacked onto each other.
```

Comment: publish the result of `str(sales1)` or `dput(sales1[1:5,])`

Comment: > str(sales1)
'data.frame': 4 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ year: int  1991 1992 1993 1994
 $ q1  : num  4.8 5.8 6 6.3
 $ q2  : num  4.1 5.2 5.6 5.9
 $ q3  : num  6 6.8 7.5 8
 $ q4  : num  6.5 7.4 7.8 8.4

Comment: > dput(sales1[1:5,])
structure(list(year = c(1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, NA), q1 = c(4.8, 
5.8, 6, 6.3, NA), q2 = c(4.1, 5.2, 5.6, 5.9, NA), q3 = c(6, 6.8, 
7.5, 8, NA), q4 = c(6.5, 7.4, 7.8, 8.4, NA)), .Names = c("year", 
"q1", "q2", "q3", "q4"), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "NA"
), class = "data.frame")
>

Comment: You do not have one series, you have a table. Thus `sales1 <- sales1[,-1]`;
`sales1 <- unlist(sales1)` convert the matrix to vector

Comment: I have upvoted this since it must be trickier than one would expect given all the  "solutions" including my original one (I have fixed it) and the original one of another (which has since been fixed as well) were/are wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format of the original data is difficult to use directly for a time series. You could try this instead:

```
sales1 <- t(sales1[,-1])
sales1 <- as.vector(sales1)
my_ts <- ts(sales1, frequency = 4, start=c(1991,1))
plot.ts(my_ts)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It works now.  the original data set had only 3 columns:  year, qtr, sales,  I had  problems so I transposed it but it did not work.  how would you do it if it had only 3 columns ?

Comment: If I had a list of three columns: year, quarter, sales, and if the data for the years and quarters was chronologically ordered, I'd  probably dispense of the first two columns with `sales <- sales[,-c(1:2), drop=T]` and use the same code as above. I think that the '`unlist()` command is then not necessary. You might want to make sure that there are no gaps in your list, like missing entries for a few years or quarters, to avoid unpleasant surprises.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it and let you know the outcome.

Comment: I made a mistake in the original answer as I didn't realize that the original matrix or data frame had to be transposed. The default reading  sequence of R is columnwise. Please note the corresponding changes, especially the use of `t()` and `as.vector()`. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
salesT<-ts(unlist(t(sales1[,-1])),start=c(1991,1),freq=4)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This line is making the times into one of the series which is unlikely what you want:

```
> salesT <- ts(sales1)
```

We need to transpose the data frame in order that it reads across the rows rather than down and we use `c` to turn the resulting matrix into a vector forming the data portion of the series.  (continued after chart)

```
# create sales1
Lines <- "year  q1  q2  q3  q4
1 1991 4.8 4.1 6.0 6.5
2 1992 5.8 5.2 6.8 7.4
3 1993 6.0 5.6 7.5 7.8
4 1994 6.3 5.9 8.0 8.4"
sales1 <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)

# convert to ts and plot
salesT <- ts(c(t(sales1[-1])), start = sales1[1, 1], freq = 4)
plot(salesT)
```

[image: screenshot]

Regarding the comment, if the data looks like this then it is more straight forward and the lines below will produce the above plot.  We have assumed that the data is sorted and starts at the bginning of a year so we do not need to use the second column:

```
Lines2 <- "year qtr sales
1  1991  q1   4.8
2  1991  q2   4.1
3  1991  q3   6.0
4  1991  q4   6.5
5  1992  q1   5.8
6  1992  q2   5.2
7  1992  q3   6.8
8  1992  q4   7.4
9  1993  q1   6.0
10 1993  q2   5.6
11 1993  q3   7.5
12 1993  q4   7.8
13 1994  q1   6.3
14 1994  q2   5.9
15 1994  q3   8.0
16 1994  q4   8.4"
sales2 <- read.table(text = Lines2, header = TRUE)

salesT2 <- ts(sales2$sales, start = sales2$year[1], freq = 4)
plot(salesT2)
```

**Update** fixed. Added response to comments.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I have to try it with the original data set which has only 3 columns of : years, qtr, sales.   I couldn't get it to work so I transposed it from the original.

Comment: Its more straight forward if you only have three columns.  See addition at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Here I think you need to format it correctly try this:

```
salesT <- ts(sales1)

ts.plot(salesT, frequency = 4, start = c(1991, 1), end = c(1994, 4)))
```

Comment: i tried it , the plot looks weird with 2 straight lines and 2 triangular shapes