# How to Plot Graph of multiple securities with multiple time series in R

Tags: r, plot

I have 5413 companies (as columns) and time period of 2000 to 2014 daily  stock price observations, 3789 is observation count in my dataset. So, now I want to plot the graphs of these companies prices and also plot the graphs of the log returns I created in separate dataframe. I illustrate some portion of the dataframe as follows

```
Date       A G L    ABA    ABB ABBEY 
2000-1-3    NA      NA      NA  NA
2000-1-4    79.5    325     NA  961  
2000-1-5    79.5    322.5   NA  945
2000-1-6    79.5    327.5   NA  952
2000-1-7    NA      327.5   NA  941  
2000-1-10   79.5    327.5   NA  946
2000-1-11   79.5    327.5   NA  888
```

and daily log returns

```
 Date      A G L    ABA      ABB         ABBEY
  2000-01-04   NA           NA   NA           NA
  2000-01-05    0 -0.007722046   NA -0.016789481
  2000-01-06    0  0.015384919   NA  0.007380107
  2000-01-07   NA  0.000000000   NA -0.011621895
  2000-01-10   NA  0.000000000   NA  0.005299429
  2000-01-11    0  0.000000000   NA -0.063270826
```

I want to plot the graphs with companies name as Y-axis and Date as X-axis, separately for each company in my dataframes. I want to show that trend or stationarity in the stock prices series has been removed by log returns
I tried `plot.ts(Price)` but it returns

```
Error in plotts(x = x, y = y, plot.type = plot.type, xy.labels = xy.labels,  : 
  cannot plot more than 10 series as "multiple"
```

Comment: please provide a reproducible example. there are several examples in SO about timeseries (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31388660/r-time-series-plot-ts). and do you want to plot all 5413 companies on one graph only?

Comment: MLavoie thank you for the suggestion link. I have searched this topic but I will admit I'm not good at graphs. I want plot graph of each column(company) indiviually, where company is at y-axis and date column is x-axis.

Answer (score 0):

so here is a couple of examples you can use. I prefer ggplot2 but it's up to you :-)

```
data <- read.table(text="
Date       AGL    ABA    ABB ABBEY 
2000-1-3    NA      NA      NA  NA
2000-1-4    79.5    325     NA  961  
2000-1-5    79.5    322.5   NA  945
2000-1-6    79.5    327.5   NA  952
2000-1-7    NA      327.5   NA  941  
2000-1-10   79.5    327.5   NA  946
2000-1-11   79.5    327.5   NA  888",
  header = TRUE)
```

format your date

```
data$Date <- as.Date(data$Date)
```

and then use your plot function

```
plot.ts(data)
```

[image]

or with ggplot2

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=data, aes(x=Date, y=AGL)) + geom_line() + geom_line(data=data, aes(x=Date, y=ABA), color="red") + geom_line(data=data, aes(x=Date, y=ABBEY), color="green") + theme_bw()
```

[image]

obviously you can change the graphics by playing with the options!

Comment: I thank you again for such thorough answer. I hope its not a stretch but can you guide me how to make graph like the example 1 you have given. I want multiple companies like you plotted ABA, AGL on y-axis and the date column on x-axis. But the thing is I have 5413 companies(columns) to be plotted in x-axis, it would be cumbersome process to give their name,so,  how can I select all the companies and plot them additionally the date formate can be into just year like 2000. Your help is highly appreciated

Comment: if you like the answer don't forget to accept the answer (of give me a +1)...but to your question why do you mean by  "I have 5413 companies(columns) to be plotted in x-axis"..the date should be the x and your column the y. this could help you https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/plot.ts.html; maybe you could add a desire output (plot) to your post

Comment: Actually I'm new here so,can't post images and still learning on editing the post. Your example 1 in which you used plot.ts(data) is very close to the output I want. I just want the Date to be on x-axis, which in the example 1 you presented in Time. Yes I will definately accept your answer, can't let your effort go wasted.

Comment: try this plot(data$Date, data$AGL, type="l"), you can change the x y labels as you which

Answer (score 0):

Import necessary R packages:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(dplyr)
```

I create a toy data.frame to make the point:

```
   df <- tribble(
         ~day, ~stock1, ~stock2,
         1,       3,        5,
         2,       2,        1,
         3,       -3,       7
       )
```

Now, using **gather** function from **dplyr** you can transform the data into **long** format:

```
df2 <- df %>% gather(stock1:stock2, key = 'stock', value= 'price')
```

Use **ggplot2** to make the plot:

```
ggplot(df2, aes(day, price, color = stock)) + geom_line()
```

Or, you could do it in one step:

```
df %>% gather(stock1:stock2, key = 'stock', value= 'price') %>%
  ggplot(aes(day, price, color = stock)) + 
  geom_line()
```

Comment: Thanks for wanting to contribute here. Code only answers are seldom helpful. Maybe you would explain how your code answers the question?